# How come if you click an ad in my game it causes the game to restart?

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I just started to experiment with ads for the first time so I am a complete beginner at this stuff. I have the ads running at the right screens which is good but if you click an ad and it takes you out of the game it causes the game to restart. I made my game in libgdx and I use the pause function and what not but it obviously doesn't call that and in fact just causes a full restart which would make a lot of users angry. Anyone else having this issue or I am doing something wrong?

I am using admob by the way.

**EDIT**

I also just realized that it happens on my nexus 5 and not my nexus 7.

Comment: I was wondering that making the libgdx view fragment-based would probably simplify these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happened to me some while ago with a game that tried to implement fb sign in functionality. The second it got back from the sign it, it restarted.

What might be happening in your case is that when you click on the add, android switches from your LibGDX activity to the admob activity. Once you come back, the onCreate method gets called again, therefore restarting your app from scratch. (A simple way to verify this is just to add a Log call everytime the app on create method is entered, and check the behaviour of your app)

If that is the case, a possible workaround for it is checking that if your game has been already initialized it should not instantiate it again.

Comment: If that's the case what is the difference between the phone and the tablet?

Comment: As far as I know there is no difference on the LibGDX side, but phones and tablets use different versions of Android, so there might be some things they handle differently. By not initializing the game again I got it to work just fine on both phones and tablets.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I fixed it with your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The restart means that your app has crashed. That's standard Android behaviour.

I suspect you have wired something up incorrectly. Look at you log. There's a good chance something hasn't been initialised that should have.

Comment: Why would it only crash on the nexus 5 and not the 7 and I don't see anything on logcat.